# Black Holes and Entangled Particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, black-holes, quantum-entanglement, event-horizon

What if you created 2 entangled particles and sent one into a black hole.

Could you measure the one you have and get information out of a black hole?

Answer (score 1):

No. The [no-communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) says that it is not possible to transmit information by only measuring one part of an entangled quantum state. Methods of communicating information using entangled states require the transmission of an equivalent amount of information through a classical (non-quantum) channel. If one part of the entangled state is inside the event horizon of a black hole then a classical channel cannot be established so no communication is possible.